# Convert SQL to Relational Algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

Please can anyone help convert the following two SQL statements to Relational Algebra

1)

```
SELECT D.Dname 
FROM Employee E, Department D
WHERE E.Dno = D.Dno
  AND E.Lname='Smith'
  AND S.Fname='John'
```

2)

```
SELECT B.Town
FROM Staff S, Branch B
WHERE S.BranchId = B.BranchId
  AND S.lName='Pincher'
  AND S.fName='Penny'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: answer]
... and I suppose you meant D.Fname = 'John' in WHERE clause

Comment: :I am also having problems in Relational Algebra question. I have posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997845/how-to-convert-sql-to-relational-algebra-in-case-of-sql-joins). Can you please help me there? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relational algebra for the second SQL statement:

π <sub>Town</sub> (σ <sub>lName = 'Pincher' ^ fName = 'Penny'</sub> (Staff |x| <sub>BranchId</sub> Branch))

Comment: :I am also having problems in Relational Algebra question. I have posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997845/how-to-convert-sql-to-relational-algebra-in-case-of-sql-joins). Can you please help me there? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

π <sub>Dname</sub> (σ <sub>Lname = 'Smith' ^ Fname = 'John'</sub> (Employee |x| <sub>Dno</sub> Department))

Comment: thanks for the answer, though i'm still comparing with some that i answered on my own, wouldnt mind if you help me with this too   `SELECT B.Town`
`FROM Staff S, Branch B`
`WHERE S.BranchId = B.BranchId`
`AND S.lName='Pincher'`
`AND S.fName='Penny`

Comment: @rcanu:I am also having problems in Relational Algebra question. I have posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997845/how-to-convert-sql-to-relational-algebra-in-case-of-sql-joins). Can you please help me there? Thanks.