# How to convert SQL to Relational Algebra in case of SQL Joins?

Tags: sql, join, relational-database, relational-algebra

I am working on SQL and Relational Algebra these days. And I am stuck on the below questions. I am able to make a SQL for the below questions but somehow my Relational Algebra that I have made doesn't looks right.

Below are my tables-

> `Employee (`**`EmployeeId`**`, EmployeeName, EmployeeCountry)`
>    `Training (`**`TrainingCode`**`, TrainingName, TrainingType, TrainingInstructor)`
>   `Outcome`  `(`**`EmployeeId, TrainingCode`**`, Grade)`

All the keys are specified with star *.

Below is the question and its SQL query as well which works fine-

> Find an Id of the Employee who has taken every training.

SQL Qyery:

```
SELECT X.EmployeeID
FROM   (SELECT EmployeeID, COUNT(*) AS NumClassesTaken 
        FROM OutCome GROUP BY EmployeeID ) 
        AS X
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ClassesAvailable 
        FROM Training) 
        AS Y
  ON X.NumClassesTaken = Y.ClassesAvailable
```

I am not able to understand what will be the relational algebra for the above query? Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: 1) I think you want natural join rather than cross product. 2) Try relational division.

Comment: @sqlvogel: Can you provide an example basis on my problem? It is totally new to me and I am facing lot of problems.. Any help will be appreciated on that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relational algebra for:

> Find an `Id` of the `Employee` who has taken *every* `training`.

Actually you need [**division `%` operator** in relational algebra](http://users.abo.fi/soini/divisionEnglish.pdf):

> `r ÷ s` is used when we wish to express queries with `“all”`:
>
> **Example:**
>
> 1. Which persons have a bank account at `ALL` the banks in the country?
> 2. Retrieve the name of employees who work on `ALL` the projects that `Jon Smith` works on?

Read also [this slid](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.science.uva.nl%2FFCN%2Fteaching%2F2012-db-ik%2Fsilberslides%2FDivsion%2520-%2520Slides%2520-%2520relational%2520algebra.pptx&ei=SpBHUvyFJsfirAeg04DgDw&usg=AFQjCNFSUPjsteHc2HDLx7yR6NcJLHgQgg&bvm=bv.53217764,d.bmk) for division operator:

You also need  query  % operator for your query: "Employee who has taken **all** training".

First list off all Training codes:

> `Training (`**`TrainingCode`**`, TrainingName, TrainingType, TrainingInstructor)`

Primary key is: **`TrainingCode`**:

> `TC =` **∏** <sub>`TrainingCode`</sub>(Training)

A pair of employeeID and trainingCode: a employee take the training.

> `ET =` **∏** <sub>`EmployeeId, TrainingCode`</sub>(Outcome)

Apply % Division operation which gives you desired employee's codes with trainingCode then apply projection to filter out employee code only.

> `Result =` **∏** <sub>`EmployeeId`</sub>(ET % TC)

["Fundamentals of Database Systems"](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/books/dbtext/elmasri94.html) is the book I always keep in my hand.

> #### 6.3.4 The DIVISION Operation
>
> The DIVISION operation is defined for convenience for dealing with
>   queries that involves `universal quantification` or the `all`
>   condition. Most RDBMS implementation with SQL as the primary query
>   language do not directly implement division. SQL has round way of
>   dealing with the type of query using EXISTS, CONTAINS and NOT EXISTS
>   key words.
>
> The general DIVISION operation applied to two relations `T(Y) = R(Z) %
>   S(X)`, where `X ⊆ Z`   and `Y = Z - X` (and hence `Z =
>   X ∪ Y`); that is `Y` is the set of attributes of `R` that are not
>   attributes of `S` e.g. `X = {A}, Z = {A, B} then Y = {B}`, `B`
>   attribute is not present in relation `S`.
>
> `T(Y)` the result of DIVISION is a relation includes a tuple *`t`* if
>   tuple `tR` appear in relation `R` with
>   `tR[Y] = t`, and with
>   `tR[X] = tS` for *`every`* tuple in
>   `S`. This means that. for a tuple *`t`* to appear in the result `T` of the DIVISION, the value of  *`t`* must be appear in `R` in combination with every tuple in `S`.

I would also like to add that the set of relational algebra operations `{`**`σ`**`,`**`∏`**`,`**`⋈`**`,`**`Χ`**`,`**`-`**`}` namely Selection, Projection, Join, Cartesian Cross and Minus is a **complete** set; that is any of the other original relational algebra operation can be expressed as a sequence of operations from this set. Division operation `%`  can also be expressed in the form of **`∏`**, **`⋈`**, and  **`-`** operations as follows:

> `T1 <-- ∏Y(R)`
>   `T2 <-- ∏Y((S Χ  T1) - R)`
>   `T3 <-- T1 - T2`

To represent your question using basic relational algebraic operation just replace R by Outcome, S by Training and attribute set Y by EmployeeId.

I hope this help.

Comment: In linked PDF, and slid you will also find some numerical example I highly encourage you to check that which will clear you how the sequence of basic set operation are equivalent to division operation.